# Divide first n square numbers 1^2, 2^2, ....... n^2 into two groups such that absolute difference of the sum of the two groups is minimum

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

lets say Given input is n = 6 (n is as large as 100000)
My task is to divide {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36} into two groups and PRINT these two groups

Possible Solution 1: dividing groups as {1, 9, 36} and {4, 16, 25} which gives abs diff as abs(46 - 45) = 1. So the minimum difference is 1 and the two groups are {1, 9, 36} and {4, 16, 25}

Possible Solution 2: Another Possible Solution is dividing groups as {9, 36} and {1, 4, 16, 25} which gives abs diff as abs(45 - 46) = 1. So the minimum difference is 1 and the two groups are {9, 36} and {1, 4, 16, 25}.

If there are multiple solutions we can print any one.
Iam trying to solve it using  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-1-n-two-groups-minimum-sum-difference/ but its not working.

I know that min difference is always 0 or 1 for n >= 6 but how  to divide them into two groups.

And can we extend this problem to cubes, fourth powers, so on.
if so what is the strategy used

Comment: Suppose $n\ge15$. Let $1\le s\le(\Sigma_{i=1}^ni^2)/2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/2$. Then $s$ is the sum of all elements in some subset of $\{1,4,9,\cdots, n^2\}$, except the following 31 numbers: 2,3,6,7,8, 11,12,15,18,19, 22,23,24,27,28, 31,32,33,43,44, 47,48,60,67,72, 76,92,96,108,112, 128. In particular, for all $n\ge6$,  $\lfloor(\Sigma_{i=1}^ni^2)/2\rfloor$ is the sum of all elements in some subset, i.e., the minimum difference in the question is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @JohnL. I have updated constraints

Comment: Please note that this is a question from an ongoing contest on codechef. Try not to answer it as it will affect the ratings of fellow candidates.
https://www.codechef.com/SEPT20B/problems/EQDIV Those who want to know the solution can wait for the contest to end and then see the accepted solutions.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to a completely different question, in a way that destroys the original question, or that renders existing answers irrelevant.

Comment: Please credit the original source where you encountered this task, and provide proper credit/link.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it violates our rules regarding programming contest questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite related to my research work, It would be helpful for me if you post the solution when you get it. But I don't think it can be solved by using pen and paper as the constraints you mentioned is quite huge.

**Solution 1 :**

Your problem statement can be re written as , Expressing a Number(P) as sum of kth Power of distinct numbers.

Now if you want to translate this to your problem Then,
P = floor[(∑N^2)/2]

As you have already stated that the difference is always 1 or 0.
The below links might help you.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X03000967?via%3Dihub
[http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Wong.pdf](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Wong.pdf)

**Solution 2:**

The other non suggestible solution to solve this is using patterns, for n>6 The difference will for a pattern 0011 with period 4. Here Diff is dependent on N and the perfect kth power we choose. According to theory of dependent relativity when Diff follows a pattern, The perfect powers must also follow a pattern because they both are dependent. Kindly let us know if you see any patterns there.

**Solution 3:**

Make two sets as odd numbers on one set and even numbers on one set, Now use swaps by using two pointers to make the difference as minimum as possible. It will not take more than two swaps.

**Solution 4:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem
Use lagrange four square theorem and evaluate a,b,c,d where s/2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 but lagrange can give duplicate values. for ex: a=c, b,d are distinct values that you got from lagranges now call a recurrence relation to split a^2 into 4 distinct values or c^2 into distinct values. Run this function till you get all distinct values.

Also please care to post here if you find any solution to this problem or if any above links  or any other links works.

Comment: re. `Solution 2`: the task hasn't been to output the smallest difference, but `Divide first n square numbers […] into two groups` / `PRINT these two groups`.

Comment: All above solutions are for printing one group and the other group is complement of the universal set.

Comment: @greybeard What or how to print is surely not in any way related to computer science and therefore completely off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked covers a similar but different problem (they partition the integers between $1$ and $n$ rather than their squares), but the same greedy algorithm of "start with the biggest number and put each one into the list whose sum is currently smaller (plus arbitrary tiebreaking)" works for this problem as well.

To analyze the algorithms, note that at each step we have 2 possible cases:

1. Adding the next number $k$ to the list with the smaller sum makes it so that the list still has a smaller sum than the other one. In this case, the difference between the two sums decreases (by $k$).
2. Adding the next number $k$ to the list with the smaller (after tiebreaking) sum makes it so that this list's sum is now greater. Hence the difference between the two sums might increase, but the difference may not exceed $k$ (which would be the case if the two sums were equal).

Hence the final difference is bounded by the last $k$ for which the second case occurs. However, we can show that both cases alternate by noting that
$$ (n + 1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 $$
and exploiting that $n^2 > 2n + 1$ for all $n > 1$.
This yields that (with the exception of choosing a list for $1$) we will choose the same list to add a number to more than twice in a row.

It follows that after placing $9$ into one of the lists we are in the following scenario:

- The difference of sums is at most 9
- If $4$ and $1$ are placed into the same group, then the final difference is at most $9 - 4 - 1 = 4$.
- If $4$ and $1$ are placed into different groups, the final difference is at most $4 - 1 = 3$.

Note that these are hard limits: in the cases where $n = 3$ we see that a final difference of $4$ cannot be avoided on all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the first n squares is $s_n = n(n+1)(2n+1) / 6$.  For n=10, the sum is 385, and the numbers 129 to 256 are the sum of a subset of these squares (found by brute force search). That range is 129 to $s_n - 129$. Since the range is large enough, containing 127 integers, we can show by induction that every integer from 129 to $s_n - 129$ is the sum of a subset of the first n squares for every $n ≥ 10$.

If $n ≥ 10$ we can start with two empty sets A and B, then add $n^2$, $(n-1)^2$, ..., $11^2$ to the set with the smaller sum, and we will end up with two sums with a difference of at most 121. Let the difference be d. Assume 0 ≤ d ≤ 121, otherwise exchange the two sets.

$\lfloor (s_n - d) / 2 \rfloor$ is the sum of a subset S of the squares from $1^2$ to $10^2$, and $\lceil (s_n + d) / 2 \rceil$ is the sum of the other squares. If we add S to A and the other squares to B, then the difference in the sums is either 0 or 1.

If $s_n$ is even, that’s it. Otherwise we pick all ways to write $s_n$ as a product $a \cdot b$ of two odd numbers ≥ 3 and try to distribute the squares into a subsets each with a sum equal to b. This will be hard if the smaller divisor a of the sum is not small, say about n. (I notice the question asks for two groups, but that's boring).

The nine cases $n ≤ 9$ would need to be handled separately.

A reasonably slow growing function other than $f(n) = n^2$ may be handled using the same method. That's just a small programming problem.

However, I just heard this is a question from a coding competition. In that case: Asking here is cheating. If you use this answer in a coding competition, you're a cheat. And I'm glad I left enough out so that at least some minimal competence is needed to get a solution.

Comment: I think DP will not work because n is large(upto 10^5) and its sum is huge

Comment: what for n to the power of three(i.e 1^3,2^3......n^3)?

Comment: @starboy [`DP will not work because n is large(upto 10^5) and [the resulting sums are] huge`](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129910/divide-first-n-square-numbers-12-22-n2-into-two-groups-such-that-ab#comment272670_129919) Are you, in full earnest, claiming a coding problem?